# How to handle validation failed 422 error in vue js on Axios post if user already exist

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios

[Vue console error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oibmZ.jpg)

Am getting this 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error while trying to do a POST request using Laravel and Vue-resource. I currently have the following codes:

```js
register() {
          this.loading = true;          
          this.axios.post('register', {
            firstname: this.firstname,
            lastname: this.lastname,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
            password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation
          })
           .then(response => {
            this.loading = false;
            this.name = '';
            this.email = '';
            this.password = '';
            this.password_confirmation = '';
            this.loginUser(response);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.loading = false;            
            if(err.response && err.response.data &&  err.response.data.errors){
              this.errors = err.response.data.errors;
              console.log(err.response.data.errors);
            }
          
          });

        }
```

Comment: I think what you need to do is to show an error in your vue application when 422 error is returned, using the error message to give user a hint where is going wrong.

Comment: PLease check vue log attached image ..I am handling error by .catch , then why error appear in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample of how I handle it in the catch() method

```
.catch(function(err){
    if(err.response.status == 422) {
        $.each(err.response.data.errors, function(key, value) {
           if(key == 'email'){
               view.emailError = err.response.data.errors.email[0]; //NB: emailError is registered in Vue data 
            }
            if(key == 'password'){
              view.passwordError = err.response.data.errors.password[0]; //NB: passwordError is registered in Vue data 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You will need a elements registered in your Vue data to hold the error like I have
"emailError" and "passwordError" or you can update the elements directly like `$('#emailErrorHolder').text(err.response.data.errors.email[0])`;